# Why is "Hidden State" at Node in Graph Neural Network Considered "Compressed" Representation?

Tags: graph-neural-network

I am reading article on [Graph Neural Network](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/topics/insights/2021/temporal-graph-networks) (GNN) and it is mentioned:

> The memory stores the states of all the nodes, acting as a compressed representation of the node’s past interactions.

Why is the hidden state or node's memory considered **compressed representation**  of the node's interaction? Isnt **compressed representation** is what auto-encoders yield?

Comment: I can't see any problem here. This phrase is definitely not used just for auto-encoders.

Comment: @Valentas sure but what is the reason to call it compressed representation? how is it compressed? Compression happens when features are reduced in a botlleneck in auto-encoders, how is compression happening here?

Comment: I didn't read the paper, but I would guess the sum of 'hidden state' dimensions is much smaller than the sum of input dimensions